# setting up secure tmpfs in fstab

Tags: mount, security, fstab

I recently set up an Ubuntu 16.04 server that I wanted to make more secure than usual, so I started researching ways to prevent known attacks.

One recommendation was to change the tmpfs /dev/shm mount to read-only. The [Ubuntu Community Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/StricterDefaults) lists the modified fstab line as:

`none    /run/shm        tmpfs   defaults,ro  0       0`

however, some external guides recommend:

`tmpfs    /run/shm        tmpfs   defaults,ro  0       0`

I understand the first field is supposed to be the /dev location or UUID, so how would `none` correctly identify the shared memory mounted device? Is it simply not necessary to specify because we are identifying it accurately enough with the 2nd and 3rd fields (mount point and filesystem type)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first field is the storage backend you want to mount. In case of `tmpfs`, there is none storage backend.

From `man fstab`

> The first field (fs_spec).
> ...
> For filesystems with no storage, any string can be used, and will show up in df(1) output, for example.
> Typical usage is `proc` for procfs; `mem`, `none`, or `tmpfs` for tmpfs.
> ...